# VirtualBox Warning: program compiled against libxml 209 using older 207

Tags: linux, virtualbox

I have installed Ubuntu Server 12.04-4 LTS.

Set to /etc/apt/sources.list

- deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian saucy contrib
- deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian raring contrib
- deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian quantal contrib
- deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian precise contrib
- deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian lucid contrib non-free
- deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian wheezy contrib
- deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian squeeze contrib non-free

After that I did

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-4.3
```

The Commandline below give me the Error
**"Warning: program compiled against libxml 209 using older 207"**

```
VBoxManage setproperty websrvauthlibrary null
```

Than I downloaded the install the Extension Pack of Linux

```
wget http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/VERSION/Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-4.3.6.vbox-extpack
VBoxManage extpack install Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-4.3.6.vbox-extpack
```

Got the same error like above with **"Warning: program compiled against libxml 209 using older 207"**

Can anybody tell what is wrong? What is wrong with libxml?

**ScreenLog**

```
VBoxManage extpack install Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-4.3.0.vbox-extpack
Warning: program compiled against libxml 209 using older 207
0%...
Progress state: NS_ERROR_FAILURE
VBoxManage: error: Failed to install "/home/thatsme/Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-4.3.0.vbox-extpack"
VBoxManage: error: The installer failed with exit code 127: Warning: program compiled against libxml 209 using older 207
VBoxManage: error: Error creating textual authentication agent: Error opening current controlling terminal for the process (`/dev/tty'): No such device or address
VBoxManage: error: Details: code NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005), component ExtPackManager, interface IExtPackManager
VBoxManage: error: Context: "int handleExtPack(HandlerArg*)" at line 1143 of file VBoxManageMisc.cpp
```

Comment: You may have installed the version meant for saucy. Uninstall virtualbox. Edit your apt sources list so that the only virtualbox line is the one for precise. yum update and install virtualbox again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Warning: program compiled against libxml 209 using older 207

It seems to be a **warning** and not an **error** so you don't have to take it so seriously :)

Besides, in your `sources.list` you should not be putting those extra repo since with 12.04 (precise) you should be ok. Those extra repos can cause a lot of trouble and interdependency problems if you don't take care.

So, I recommend you to only left your `sources.list` with the only needed for your distribution:

```
deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian precise contrib
```

Also, you can try to do a package upgrade with `sudo apt-get update` or `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` to see if the version issue dissapear with a `libxml` upgrade.

Also, you can try to force an update on `libxml` by issuing `sudo apt-get install libxml` to see if that solves your warning.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Are you installing the Extension Pack on the Host system or on the (Virtual) guest system? What **is** your Host system, assuming Ubuntu-server is the guest OS?

FYI: It should be installed on the Host system, and your regular username `thatsme` should be added to the `vboxusers` group

```
    sudo usermod -aG vboxusers thatsme
```

As for the libxml errors, they *should* be harmless; feel free to check out [this](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=52751) thread on the virtualbox forums, where a user has similar issues.